# Odoo Blank screen with no UI , on docker container setup on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, odoo-9, odoo-view, postgresql-9.6

Configuration :

- AWS
- Ubuntu linux
- Running docker :`docker -v` = Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638
- Postgresql - `"PG_MAJOR=9.6", "PG_VERSION=9.6.0-1.pgdg80+1"`
- Odoo - `"ODOO_VERSION=9.0","ODOO_RELEASE=20160726"`

Problem :

- I am able to login to odoo. After login the website page opens, good till now. After any option I go to, 'Employment' , 'Notes' , etc which I have previous installed a simple blank page appears as shared below nothing else.
- FYI, it was running smoothly for around 100 days , after which recently containers stopped running [may due to disk full on aws instance]. I made some space and restarted the containers.
- New clean instances of db [postgresql 9.6] and odoo  [9] if recreated from same images they work fine.
- Using this containers and clones of it do not work with any database , old or new.
- Earlier pure html page was loading , after couple of restarts of linux, docker and container  it magically started showing proper login page.

My conclusions :

- Login was possible, so db connection is good to go.

[image: Odoo plain view page]

Comment: What do your log files say? There should be a postgresql.log file and an openerp-server.log

Comment: @DanielC , `/var/lib/postgreql` and `/var/lib/odoo` both are empty directory. and no logging is setup. Is there any other place to look for, if i missed ?